# Prevent subdomains with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am considering moving one of my very static sites to use Amazon's Simple Storage Service. I have read a few articles describing how I can load the files in and set things up so that http://www.example.com/ is directed at those files, but is there a way I can ensure that people who go to http://example.com/ get 301'd to http://www.example.com/?

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up for those who find this, S3 now support main root domain. You no longer have to do a redirect.